# Fahrenheit to Celsius in Python

Tags: python, csv

I tried to transfer the dataset('weatherData.csv') from Fahrenheit to Celsius, but it failed.

code:

```
temp_f= weatherData[:,0] # temperature in Fahrenheit
print(temp_f)
```

output:

```
print(convert_c(temp_f))
[ 47.97057286  23.5196821   62.83761601  29.76327695  62.6681284
  63.33399079  54.64851146  62.1412634   54.55748896  33.56236716
  26.92654588  55.44675999  24.02596628  49.26664652   3.51260452
  51.13868443  43.69058214  51.38528221  49.4359487   28.64250039
  20.04998871  37.43606552  65.42938148  89.01975239  50.5901757
  47.67924772  78.88510636  67.9751587   53.73656348  31.71740073
  10.32841868  44.23632324  23.19185571  43.19495991  87.09491419
  62.85445583   4.26462991  41.1137659   66.78859715  51.11778269
  83.24258749  36.90624107 105.906144    79.41590156  18.82727136
  38.37076257  54.2336612   81.45364553  35.42310806  81.57576471]
```

How to transfer these data to Celsius? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
There is nothing in your posting that attempts to covert the values -- a call to an undefined function doesn't qualify.

Comment: If you don't know how to write the function, search for "Python temperature convert".  We expect you to do this research before posting here.

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def to_celsius(fah):
    fah -= 32
    return fah / 1.8

data = [47.97057286, ... ]
new_data = list(map(to_celsius, data))
print(new_data)

# [8.872540477777775, ... ]
```